# Jersey implementing ContextResolver<JAXBContext> in Spring

Tags: json, spring, jaxb, jersey

So I am writing a Spring(2.5( + Jersey(1.1.4.1) and trying to create a JSONConfiguration using a ContextResolver.  Here is the code:

```
package com.rhigdon.jersey.config;

import com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONConfiguration;
import com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONJAXBContext;

import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;

@Provider
public final class JAXBContextResolver implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext> {
  private JAXBContext context;

  public JAXBContextResolver() throws Exception {
    this.context = new JSONJAXBContext(JSONConfiguration.mappedJettison().build(), "com.rhigdon.core.model.");
  }

  public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> aClass) {
    return context;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately my app is still returning the default mapping:

> {"id":"1","question":"What is/was the
>   name of your first pet?"}

When I debug the application it never actually hits this code.  Is this due to using the SpringServlet?  Here is my Jersey Config in my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Spring Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Spring Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Anyone have a similar setup with JSONConfiguration working?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to register your provider in your spring context:

```
<bean class="com.company.jersey.config.JAXBContextResolver"/>
```

Or, if you are using annotation-based configuration, you need to annotate your provider class with `@Component` and include something like

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.jersey" />
```

to your application context configuration.

Comment: This was a pretty obvious solution but I wanted to answer in case anyone else had a mind blank like me. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using jersey version 1.10 and I don't have the @Component annotation nor the bean definition, and it works without it.

Answer (score -4):

Jersey REST Service
    com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet
    
        com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages
        ca.gc.cbsa.ezfw.foundation.webservice
    
    1

Comment: How does this answer help solve the problem? Please explain your answer.

Comment: Do not force people to use Spring when they don´t want to.